# LINQ SQL Trying to merge 3 recordsets into one

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have three sets of data representing a counted value, grouped by country code.

```
select distinct m.CountryCode, count(m.MetricId) as 'Impressions'
from Metrics m
  inner join impressions i on m.MetricId = i.MetricId
where ...
group by m.CountryCode

select distinct m.CountryCode, count(m.MetricId) as 'Conversions'
from Metrics m
  inner join Conversions c on m.MetricId = c.MetricId
where ...
group by m.CountryCode
```

..and there's a third one that joins with a table called "Leads"

So each of these give me a nice set of distinct country codes and a corresponding number.

```
  CountryCode    Impressions
    AU             25
    DE             34
    US             264



   CountryCode    Conversions
    AU             11
    US             140
```

something like that.  so my goal is to get all three recordsets merged to one that looks like this:

```
CountryCode    Impressions    Conversions    Leads
US             264             140           98
```

I'd like to learn how to do this with LINQ and without doing three queries.  There's gotta be a more straightforward approach but I've been working on it too long and my eyes aren't seeing it.  Would appreciate a nudge in the proper direction, thanks

Comment: have you looked up or done a google search on linq.Join ?

Comment: yes, I have LinqPad and have been working through the C# Nutshell examples.  I've got lots of attempts...the one that is closest basically pops out three anonymous objects and then a final linq statement to join the three and tailor the end result...but it is wonky as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var qry1 = (from m in Db.Metrics
                    join i in Db.Impressions on m.MetricId equals i.MetricId
                    //where 
                    group m by m.CountryCode into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        CountryCode = grp.Key,
                        Impressions = grp.Count()
                    });

        var qry2 = (from m in Db.Metrics
                    join c in Db.Conversions on m.MetricId equals c.MetricId
                    //where 
                    group m by m.CountryCode into grp
                    select new
                    {
                        CountryCode = grp.Key,
                        Conversions = grp.Count()
                    });

        var result = (from x in qry1
                      join y in qry2 on x.CountryCode equals y.CountryCode
                      select new
                      {
                          CountryCode = x.CountryCode,
                          Impressions = x.Impressions,
                          Conversions = y.Conversions
                      });

        var lst = result.ToList();
```

The first 2 queries are lazy, they will not yet execute. The result-variable just joins them together and the last part executes the final query and materializes the objects.
Splitting these in their separate queries can be helpfull in keeping it simpler.

Comment: I understand, thanks for taking a moment to respond. That's just how I envisioned it would be but I couldn't make it click for some reason...too many hours staring at code :)